# Xero integration with Mysql

Tags: mysql, integration, xero-api

Perhaps this is so obvious I shouldn't ask!  We have succesfully linked to Xero using our own XeroApp & php, and retrieved a complete set of ACCREC data.  Next step is to integrate this with the data in our MySQL system.  My question is what are the options and what is considered best practice.  For example we could 
a)  make a live call to the Xero API in multiple places where we want display the status of a receivable invoice (paid or unpaid) or 
b) populate a MySQL table with Xero data on a schduled basis - with an option to update on request
c) more likely - something we have not thought of...
Thank you for your help,  Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ultimately a design decision on your part, but as a potential third option you could look into using [webhooks](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/overview) - it would mean you could maintain up-to-date invoice data without having to schedule/poll the Xero API unnecessarily.

Good luck!

Comment: One additional thing to think about -- Xero has some pretty low API rate limits, so if you _do_ go the real-time request route, watch out for the rate limits or make sure you degrade gracefully if Xero is unavailable.

Comment: thank you both - all now working with mysql tables populated with Xero data and looking at webhooks for future